# Spring form autocomplete="false" is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to use autocomplete="false" in my registration form for remove autocomplete the field (UserName and Password) but it not work.

I read the attribute autocomplete from this site https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input

This is my code and UI snapshot.

```
[![<form:form method="POST"  action="${contextPath}/register"  modelAttribute="registerForm"
    class="form-signin" >
     <input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
    <spring:bind path="username">
     <label class="label">Username</label>
      <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:input type="text" path="username" class="form-control"
           autofocus="true" autocomplete="false"  />
        <form:errors path="username" cssStyle="color:#ff0000;"></form:errors>
      </div>
    </spring:bind>
    <spring:bind path="email">
     <label class="label">Email</label>
      <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:input id="email" type="email" autocomplete="1" path="email"
          class="form-control" name="email"
          pattern="\[a-z0-9._%+-\]+@\[a-z0-9.-\]+\.\[a-z\]{2,3}$"/>
        <form:errors path="email" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"></form:errors>
      </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="password">
     <label class="label">Password</label>
      <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="false" id="password"></form:input>
        <form:errors path="password" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"></form:errors>
      </div>
    </spring:bind>

     <button class="btn btn-primary auth-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form:form>][1]][1]
```

Comment: try autocomplete="off" & may be hard reload page.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `autocomplete="off"`
it's supposed to solve your problems